# Looping through column whose column is specified by a variable and whose row is i

Tags: excel, vba, loops, vlookup

I am attempting to create a macro to autofill a column with a VLOOKUP. The macro calls function FindNectEmpty that finds the next empty cell, and that cell is set as variable OpenCellVoucher (This is the column header). The same function is called to find the empty cell underneath the OpenCellVoucher cell (that cell is variable FillCellVoucher). I then want to do a VLOOKUP on all the cells in that column starting with that cell. This is what I have, but I am getting on error on this line that an object is required. Why is this not an object? Any ideas to fix this?

```
 Range(FillCellVoucher.Column, i).Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(J2,   DollarRanges.Range("$A$2:$B$14"), 2, 1)

Dim OpenCellVoucher As Range
   Dim FillCellVoucher As Range
   Dim lngRow As Long

 Set NextCell = FindNextEmpty(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Range("A1"))
   ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Select
   NextCell.Value = "Dollar Range of Remaining Balance"

   'Find Open Vouchering column
   Set OpenCellVoucher = Worksheets("Master").Range("A1:O1").Find("Open for Vouchering Amt",   =xlPart)   
   'Looks up next empty cell in row
   Set FillCellVoucher = FindNextEmpty(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Range("A2"))
   ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Select
   lngRow = Cells(Rows.Count, OpenCellVoucher.Column).End(xlUp).Row
       For i = 1 To lngRow
   Range(i, FillCellVoucher.Column).Formula = _
   "=VLookup(J" & i + 1 & ", 'DollarRanges'!$A$2:$B$14, 2, 1)"
   Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set a formula in a cell you need to assign astring that is the formula:

```
Range(FillCellVoucher.Column, i).Formula = _
    "=VLookup(J2, DollarRanges.Range(" & "$A$2:$B$14" & "), 2, 1)"
```

I think the "J2" is what you hope to be changing as you incert in the cells going down. If this is your intent then:

```
Range(FillCellVoucher.Column, i).Formula = _
    "=VLookup(J" & i + 1 & ", DollarRanges.Range(" & "$A$2:$B$14" & "), 2, 1)"
```

I do not understand what "DollarRanges" is but if this works for you  then I do not need to know.

Hope this helps.

Comment: DollarRanges is the sheet that holds table that holds the table array part of the VLookup. I just tried what you suggested and I am now getting a new error: Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed.

Comment: When you reference in another sheet in a Fromula: not "DollarRanges." but "DollarRanges!" and if the tab name has paces then it is "  'Tab Name'!Rang...  " although you could incert the single quites around the Tab Name all the time.

Comment: Just changed it and still getting the same error! :(

Comment: "=VLookup(J" & i + 1 & ", 'DollarRanges'!A$2:$B$14, 2, 1)"

Comment: I am still getting the same error. I cannot figure out why this wouldn't work! FillCellVoucher is stored as a range.. does that matter?

Comment: if you fill out a column then the first dim is variable, not the second-- (row, column): Range(i, FillCellVoucher.Column).Formula = _

Comment: For i = 1 To lngRow
   Range(i, FillCellVoucher.Column).Formula = _
   "=VLookup(J" & i + 1 & ", 'DollarRanges'!.Range(" & "$A$2:$B$14" & "), 2, 1)"
   Next i

Comment: I do not know what you are doing with the first formula (Application....) The correct code inside the loop: ... & ", 'DollarRanges'!$A$2:$B$14, 2, 1)"

Comment: I edited out that part to just leave what was relevant. I made the changes and it still does not like it. Can you think of another way to go about getting the same results? I can't think of anything!

Comment: How would the formula look if you were entering it by hand?

Comment: Using regular excel it looks like this: =VLOOKUP(J2,DollarRanges!$A$2:$B$14,2,1)

Comment: Is it always "J2" in all the rows down?

Comment: Well with VLookups, I believe it needs to travel down the list.. it is looking up a dollar amount in the J column and referencing a dollar range worksheet to put it in a category. So the first is J2, then J3, etc.

Comment: That's what you already have covered in the code. What does it mean "not working"?

Comment: I am still getting the Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed error.

Comment: No idea! but this exchange of messages is not working. You might want to find someone to look at the workbook itself to figure out what's wrong. There could be many reasons that are not code-related. Who knows what you've got there. In any case, I believe we have exhasted this venue. Sorry and good luck.

Comment: Thank you for getting me further on it! :)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! The code could definitely be simplified.. but here it is:

```
Dim OpenCellVoucher As Range
   Dim FillCellVoucher As Range
   Dim myAddress As String
   Dim myColumn As String
   Dim myAdd As String
   Dim CellSelect As String

   'Find Open Vouchering column
   Set OpenCellVoucher = Worksheets("Master").Range("A1:O1").Find("Open for Vouchering Amt", lookat:=xlPart)
   'Looks up next empty cell in row
   Set FillCellVoucher = FindNextEmpty(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Range("A2"))
   ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Select
   myAddress = FillCellVoucher.Address
   myAdd = Left(myAddress, 2)
   myColumn = Right(myAdd, 1)
   For i = 1 To RowsUsed
   CellSelect = myColumn & i + 1
   ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Range(CellSelect).Formula = _
   "=VLookup(J" & i + 1 & ", 'DollarRanges'!$A$2:$B$14, 2, 1)"
   Next i
```